# apirtc - How to know if someone is already in a call or conversation?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I use apirtc in Javascript to do video calls and conversations, I want my users to do only one call or one conversation at a time.
So I'm looking how can I can see if an user is already in a call or in a conversation to disable call on him if another user wants to call.
I tried this but it only return the conversations of the active contact :

```
Session.getActiveConversations(); 
Session.getCalls();
```

Is there a way to get all Calls or Conversations ? Or another way to check if a contact is in a active call or active conversation ?

Comment: Session can only return the status of the logged-in user. It can't handle other users status.

Comment: While calling a person, we will get a declined response with the user status. Currently, that's the only way we can identify the user is busy or not.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to find another way to integrate apirtc.